# Conteúdo da pergunta em cima dos botões

Tags: bug, status-pronto, filas-de-análise, layout

Ao rolar pra baixo na página de análise, o conteúdo da pergunta fica em cima dos botões. Por hora só vi esse caso onde contém imagem no corpo da pergunta, não sei se tem relação.

[Análise](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/267028) em que eu vi o bug

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isso também acontece com o [botão de timeline da resposta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRPOV.png)

Comment: Parece que esses elementos (botão de timeline da resposta, a pergunta, informações à direita sobre dados a mais da pergunta) estão mais próximos de nós leitores no eixo Z do que essa caixinha com os botões. Ela só se sobrepõe ao texto da resposta

Comment: O "new contributor" [também](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2Izp.png)

Comment: stack overflow company, "sinônimo" de qualidade -- mais (de soma) **ironicamente** é que o site foi inicialmente idealizado para perguntas sobre programação, ou seja, o site principal atrai este tipo de publico, contendo muitas perguntas sobre HTML e CSS

Comment: @JNat, resolveu o problema com as informações à direita. Porém, o botão de timeline, a tag de "new contributor" e também os botões dos comentários estão sobrepondo-se. Também acontece com o símbolo de "olho cortado" da resposta escondida. Já já subo os prints

Comment: Os símbolos de timeline e o olho cortado: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zh6hh.png Tag de "new contributor", botões dos comentários e mensagem de comentários desativados: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbR6N.png E finalmente a pergunta se sobrepondo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUlml.png

Comment: Acabei de ver que a coluna "Stack Exchange Network" do footer também tem esse mesmo problema: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7igh.png ; mas as outras colunas estão tranquilas